# Best way to check that a list of items exists in an SQL database column?

Tags: sql, list, exists

If I have a list of items, say

```
apples
pairs
pomegranites
```

and I want to identify any that don't exist in the 'fruit' column in an SQL DB table.

- Fast performance is the main concern.
- Needs to be portable over different SQL implementations.
- The input list could contain an arbitrary number of entries.

I can think of a few ways to do it, thought I'd throw it out there and see what you folks think.

Comment: Oh, and I don't care what order the items are in the table, it's just whether each item exists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the list of fruits you are selecting from can be arbitrarily long, I would suggest the following:

```
create table FruitList (FruitName char(30))
insert into FruitList values ('apples'), ('pears'), ('oranges')

select * from FruitList left outer join AllFruits on AllFruits.fruit = FruitList.FruitName
where AllFruits.fruit is null
```

A left outer join should be much faster than "not in" or other kinds of queries.

Comment: +1 but FWIW you need each tuple parenthesized separately: VALUES ('apples'), ('pears'), ('oranges'), ...

Comment: Thanks @Bill.  I don't use VALUES much, should have checked my reference first. Fixed.

Comment: Probably the best option. if you don't want to create a table, you can create a table variable instead to do the same thing and it will be destroyed when your query ends.

Comment: Sneaky work around for inserting a bunch of test records when the values clause only lets you do one at a  time

insert mytable(field)
select 'apples'
union all
select 'Pears'
union all
select 'oranges'

Answer (score 3):

Make the search list into a string that looks like '|fruit1|fruit2|...fruitn|' and make your where clause:

```
where
  @FruitListString not like '%|' + fruit + '|%'
```

Or, parse the aforementioned string into a temp table or table variable and do `where not in (select fruit from temptable)`. Depending on the number of items you're searching for and the number of items being searched, this method could be faster.

Comment: +1 for the innovative Joel Spolsky solution!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause#337817

Answer (score 2):

```
if exists(select top 1 name from fruit where name in ('apples', 'pairs', 'pomegranates'))
  PRINT 'one exists'
```

Comment: That only says a fruit exists, not the list of fruits that DON'T exist.

Comment: I don't see where he says he needs the rest of the fruits in the table, just whether or not one of this does exist.

Comment: Sorry, I need to identify the fruits that are in my list but don't exist in the table.